# Word for 'of or related to division'

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a program with a numeric parser. The operations involved are multiplying, dividing, squaring, and cubing.

In order to define what kind of objects can be multiplied, divided, etc with what, I'm trying to name classes that define these relationships. Currently, I have `MultiplicativeRelationship`, `CubicRelationship`, `QuadraticRelationship`... and a divivitive relationship?

I can't think of a word that means 'of or relating to division'!

Divisible is the first word that comes to mind, but this can't be right because the relationship itself isn't divisible. The relationship describes other things that are divisible, making it a ________ relationship.

In short: 
Multiplication is to Multiplicative as Division is to ________

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps *fractional*.

Comment: Isn't that still called _multiplicative_?

Comment: Divisional exists, but it relates to a division of an organization, not to the mathematical operation: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/divisional

Comment: Per the OED, it would be *divisive*. Multiplicative: "Tending to multiply or increase; **having the quality or function of multiplying**." Divisive: "**Having the quality or function of dividing**; causing or expressing division or distribution; making or perceiving distinctions, analytical."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because naming variables or classes is off-topic.

Comment: I disagree with this being off topic. The author came across an issue while programming, but the issue isn't related to programming per se.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it involves naming variables in computer code.

Comment: Division is just multiplication by the inverse, so inverse-multiplicative.

Comment: There's also the issue that divisibility isn't symmetric.

Comment: "Divisible is the first word that comes to mind, but this can't be right because the relationship itself isn't divisible." This is also true of the multiplicative relationship. The relationship itself isn't multiplicative.  At the risk of straying out scope, is there a need to use a class, or would a method do? If so, then maybe just can_divide(numerator,denominator).

Comment: While 'divisive' has a near-compelling default sense, it is still the only word to use here. Context will obviously disambiguate.

Comment: Don't name classes with obscure words nobody knows. That just makes you a terrible programmer.

Answer (score 0):

*[multiplicative](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multiplicative)*: tending or having the power to multiply.

*[additive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/additive)*: of, relating to, or characterized by addition.

*[subtractive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subtractive)*: tending to subtract

So,

***divisitive*** should be ***tending to division***. Yes, this word does not exist in any of the standard (or auxiliary) dictionaries. If you use it, there is no harm. Few authors have already used it in their respective books.

Citation 1: [Handbook of Research on Mathematics Teaching and Learning by Douglas A. Grouws](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=N_wnDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA317&lpg=PA317&dq=%22divisitive%22&source=bl&ots=zj1zktrEYL&sig=ACfU3U0bwjfzdAhcixrqsp-fgLSkA5p6zA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjHo-_64-HhAhXESH0KHa2OBII4ChDoATAAegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=%22divisitive%22&f=false)

> Situations must be developed in which children systematically build their understanding of principles that underlie the invariance and the compensation for variation within additive, subtractive, multiplicative and ***divisitive*** relations and operations.

Citation 2: [Handbook of Research on Software Engineering and Productivity Technologies by by Ramachandran, Muthu](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=7O30Y57dNXgC&pg=PA407&lpg=PA407&dq=%22divisitive%22%20define&source=bl&ots=AZa8VP0aUf&sig=ACfU3U36AN5Jlhh-SUvT1DSsX5Z_bT03bg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmwu-A5uHhAhUZXn0KHb7CD0oQ6AEwA3oECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22divisitive%22%20define&f=false) [Leeds Metropolitian Univeristy, UK]

Comment: Hello, Ubi. I'd better point out that while 'If you use it, there is no harm' is open to debate, suggesting a non-standard answer is not considered appropriate on ELU.

Answer (score -1):

Although I'd love the answer to be 'divisive', I'm not sure there's a direct equivalent. In mathematics we speak of the 'multiplicative inverse' which is too much of a mouthful for your purposes. The term 'reciprocal' can be used to mean the same thing, but doesn't fit your pattern.

(You could try asking over at the [SE Maths site](https://math.stackexchange.com/).)

Answer (score -1):

I would propose

**DivisibleRelationship**

because *multiplicative* is an adjective meaning

> Tending to multiply or capable of multiplying ([American Heritage](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/multiplicative))

Compare this with the definition of *divisible*:

> Capable of being divided ([American Heritage](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/divisible))

Comment: One could say "multiplicati*on* : multiplicati*ve* :: divisi*on* : divisi*ve*, but this is simply a case of analogy of spelling, and doesn't take into account the differences in meaning of the words.